# If a muslim doubts the Quran, does he immediately become a non-muslim?

Tags: quran

Let's say a muslim reads something in the Quran and starts to get confused. As a result, he starts to slightly doubt the Quran as the word of God. So he starts to do some research on the verse(s) the confused him and after a few minutes, he finds his answer. His doubts are finally gone. Does this mean that during those few minutes he became a non-muslim? Does he have to say Shahadah again to become muslim?

Even if a muslim doubts the Quran for a split second, does that make him a non-muslim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### All perfect praise be to Allah

> **Some of the Sahaabah complained about the waswaas that was bothering
>   them.** Some of the companions of the Messenger of Allaah (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) came to the Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allaah be upon him) and said to him, **‘We find in
>   ourselves thoughts that are too terrible to speak of.’ He said, ‘Are
>   you really having such thoughts?’ They said, ‘Yes.’ He said, ‘That is
>   a clear sign of faith.**’”(Narrated by Muslim, 132).
>
> **Al-Nawawi said in his commentary on this hadeeth** (narration): “The
>   Prophet’s words, ‘That is a clear sign of faith’ means, **the fact that
>   think of this waswaas as something terrible is a clear sign of faith**,
>   for if you dare not utter it and you are so afraid of it and of
>   speaking of it, let alone believing it, this is the sign of one who
>   has achieved perfect faith and who is free of doubt.” [from here](https://islamqa.info/en/25778)

So, according to the situation you have described, if the person's thought is that ***oh i can't understand this things, this seems like such and such which is not possible, let me search about it and clear my doubts*** than thats ok, thats the faith above hadees is talking about.

Another hadees:

> It was narrated from Ibn ‘Abbas (may Allah be pleased with them both)
>   that a man came to the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon
>   him) and said, **“I think thoughts to myself, which I would rather be
>   burnt to a cinder than speak of them.” The Prophet (peace and
>   blessings of Allah be upon him) said, “Praise be to Allah, Who has
>   reduced all his [the Shaytan’s] plots to mere whispers.”** (Abu Dawood).

So, such whispers has no effect.

But, if after finding any confusion in Quran, person thinks like, ***oh, this is impossible that a true religion and a true God will say anything like this, i think islam is not true religon*** (nauzubillah) or any such thing, then this is different. In a sense that muslim is not supposed to think like that, he must research about it, find the truth about it and its explanation. But not to doubt Allah or his words immediately.

> The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said, **“Allah
>   will forgive my ummah (followers) for any insinuating whispers that
>   may cross their minds, so long as they do not act upon it or speak of
>   it.”** (Agreed upon- BUkhari/Muslim)

So, this is also **not a very big problem, just a little change of thinking is required.** Because this kind of thoughts are forgiven by Allah according to all above ahadees.

I will also like to quote:

> *Shaykh al-Islam Ibn Taymiyah (may Allah have mercy on him) said in Kitab al-Eeman: “The believer may suffer from the whispers of the
>   Shaytan insinuating thoughts of kufr (disbelief), which may make him
>   feel distressed. The Sahabah (may Allah be pleased with them) said, ‘O
>   Messenger of Allah, some of us think thoughts which we would rather
>   fall from heaven to earth than speak of them.’ He said, ‘That is a
>   clear sign of faith.’ According to one report, ‘… thoughts which are
>   too terrible to speak of.’ He said, ‘Praise be to Allah, Who has
>   reduced all his [the Shaytan’s] plots to mere whispers,’ meaning that
>   the fact that these whispers come, but they are so greatly disliked,
>   and they are pushed away from the heart, is a clear sign of faith.
>   This is like the mujahid (warrior) to whom the enemy comes, but he
>   resists him until he overwhelms him, and this is a mighty jihad
>   (battle)… Hence the seekers of knowledge and devoted worshippers
>   experience waswas and doubts which others do not face, because they
>   (the others) are not following the way prescribed by Allah, rather
>   they are following their own whims and desires and neglecting to
>   remember their Lord. This is what the Shaytan wants, in contrast to
>   those who are striving to draw closer to their Lord by seeking
>   knowledge and worshipping Him. He is their enemy and seeks to prevent
>   them from drawing closer to Allah.” (p.147 of the Indian edition)* 
> from [Suffering From Waswas (Insinuating Whispers) of the Shaytan](https://islamqa.info/en/12315)

But, **if someone thinks he had severe waswasa from shaitan and he had his heart convinced for that waswasa for even some seconds, he should repent to Allah, make taubah, ask Allah to protect him from such wasawas, and better to repeat shahadah with his pure heart.** Repeating shahadah is just to **ensure his imaan**, otherwise **no one is declaring him kafir. He had a bad thought, and then it is clear. So its ok**, but repeating shahadah will be still better, saying shahadah again and again is also a zikar which enhances imaan.

### Allah knows best

Comment: Thank you. That was extremely helpful. But what if a muslim prays Salah while these wasawas are still bothering him? Will his Salah be accepted? Or does he have to clear all doubts before praying Salah?

Comment: @curiosity As i mentioned ahadees, wasawas are forgiven to muslim ummah by Allah, so there is no need to repeat the salah, but yes, this should be priority number 1 to get these doubts cleared ASAP. And follow the thing i mentioned about changing the thinking or mind set on any doubt. On any doubt we should not start thinking islam is false religion or anything like that, rather we should be thinking to clear this doubt ASAP.

Comment: And what if a muslim dies with these doubts (while still believing in Islam and the Quran)?

Comment: Allah knows best.... no one can be sure of anything after death, its Allah who will decide his fate. We should pray for our dead people.